# Comic about a young woman monster hunter

Tags: story-identification, comics

This is going to be a very vague question, but it's bugging me that I can't remember this comic that I liked when I was younger. I only ever read one like volume of it, not a single comic book. I imagine it wasn't very popular because I don't think I've ever heard of it since.

I would have read it in the early 2000's, but I believe it was from the late 90's and I think it took place in the future. It was about a young woman who found out she was some sort of monster hunter. I *think* she was asian, but I wouldn't swear to it. She maaaaayyyy have had purple hair, but I could be imagining that. I believe she had some guy who was like a guide to her.

I know this is very vague and I'm sorry! If I think of any other details, I'll update. If you know any comics that sound like this, please let me know! lol

Update:
I want to say the guide in the series was a man, not a creature or anything like that. I believe the girl used laser guns and possibly a sword to fight.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If an incorrect answer comes up, it's a good opportunity for you to [edit] your question with details that the answer made you realize.

Comment: @Luke - What sort of monsters did she hunt? Were they large monsters like dragons, or was it more along the lines of vampires and werewolves? Also, what sort of weapons/attacks did she use? Swords? Guns? Magic?

Comment: I don't think there was magic involved. I believe she used guns (but like laser guns, not like guns irl) and possibly a sword.

Comment: I don't remember specifics about the monsters really

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of Joss Whedon's *[Fray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fray_(comics))*, a sequel to *Buffy: the Vampire Slayer*

[image: Front cover of Fray #1]

> Centuries have passed since the last Slayer was called. Demons were banished from the Earth at some point in the 21st century by an unnamed Slayer and her friends, and the Watchers' Council has decayed into a group of crazed fanatics. The vampires (dubbed lurks) have now returned and haunt the city. To combat this threat, a new Slayer is called: a professional thief named Melaka Fray. With the Watchers' Council ineffective, a group of "neutral" demons send the demon Urkonn to prepare Melaka for the war that is sure to come.
>
> Although training hard and feeling confident, Mel finds herself out of her depth when she fights the vampire Icarus. Years before, Icarus severely injured Mel and killed her twin brother, Harth. Mel discovers that Harth was not actually killed: after being bitten by Icarus, he bit back and fed off the vampire, becoming a vampire himself. Since he was the Slayer's twin, he has the visions and instinctive knowledge that should have been hers: he knew what Mel is long before she did, and also knew how to become a vampire.
>
> Disheartened, Mel refuses to fight, until she discovers the body of her young friend, a girl named Loo, with her neck snapped. Determined to avenge her, Mel rallies the inhabitants of the slums to fight against the vampires. Police officer Erin Fray (Mel's older sister) convinces some of the local law enforcement to also join in the crusade.

Mel does have purple-tipped hair, and she was guided by Urkonn.

[image: Image of Melaka with purple-tipped hair]

Comment: That came up in my search and it's somewhat similar, but I'm pretty sure that's not it. Thank you, though!!!

Comment: I accept that it's not the correct answer, but does answering why this doesn't match help refine your question at all?

Comment: This looks a little more modern/recent than what (I think) I remember. I want to say the guide in the series I'm thinking of was a man, as opposed to a beast like Urkonn. I also don't believe it was specifically vampires she was fighting.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more details.